# Присвоение значения свойству каждого элемента массива true/false

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть массив и в каждом его элементе есть свойство `hide`. При сравнивании приходит элемент с нужными полями массива, которые должны быть у меня в таблицы. Вообщем, просто нужно поменять `true` на `false` или наоборот. Как это сделать?
Массив `columnDefs` - это оригинал. А массив `checkedValues` - приходит в ответ на действие снятия или становления галочки у `checkbox`. Эти два массива и сравниваются.

```
 handleChangeVisible = (checkedValues) => {
    this.setState({
      columnDefs: this.state.columnDefs.filter(
        e => checkedValues.indexOf(e.field) !== -1
      )
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы выбрали неподходящую функцию `filter`, тк при его использовании вы "удаляете" из стайта `checkedValues` и вернуть его уже не получится так просто. Можно пропустить массив через `map`, и при совпадении - скрывать:

```
handleChangeVisible = (checkedValues) => {
    this.setState({
      columnDefs: this.state.columnDefs.map(
        column => ~checkedValues.indexOf(column.field)
            //если есть совпадение - прячем
            ? {...column, hide: true}
            //если нет - показываем
            : {...column, hide: false}
      )
    });
  };
```

Comment: Блин, парень, ты просто сэкономил мне уйму времени. Я всё таки исправил ~checkedValues.indexOf(column.field) на           checkedValues.indexOf(column.field) === -1
потому что столбцы сначала все показываются. Супер! Спасибо!